# Node.js node_modules checked into git with Linux/Unix & Windows developers?

Tags: node.js, git, node-modules

A work colleague and I are building a Node.js webapp. I'm running in a Unix environment (Mac OSX) and he's running Windows. The [current advice](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/faq.html#Should-I-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git) with regards to the node_modules folder is that this should be checked in to source control (git) for apps that you deploy (but not for packages in npm).

However, we're running into issues with compiled packages (if that's the correct term) such as [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.org/package/canvas). When I run `npm install canvas` and he runs `npm install canvas`, we both get very different looking node_modules/canvas folders, and this obviously causes source-code conflicts.

How do we work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason of putting node_modules in git is to lock dependencies of dependencies as mentioned here http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html. So you can be sure everything you have will work even if somebody remove dependent module from npm.

But yes, this approach may cause problems like you got.
I personally prefer not putting node_modules to git, and use `npm shrinkwrap` instead for dependency locking as described here https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html.

Answer (score 2):

That is the exact reason you do not put `node_modules` into the project repository, but instead maintain the dependency json list.

Moreover, node_modules will very likely be the heaviest folder in your project, playing the major role in overloading your repository.

---

In advice, they suggest not using npm to manage dependencies for deployment in production. That is meaningful, you do not want your production server to depend on extra services (npm itself, and authors of modules)

In your case, you are developing, and npm suggests you to use dependencies too:

> • Use npm to manage dependencies in your dev environment

Comment: I think you're right. But it's weird that this advice (to put modules into source-control) comes direct from the horses mouth (the npm people).

Comment: @SundayIronfoot yes, there is some truth on the other side as I guessed. Modified the question. They actually tell you to use NPM for development too, but not for production server itself.